# How do I write the following statements formally?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I write the following statements formally ?

1. Any two natural numbers have a common multiple.
2. There is a real number which is a square of an integer.

I tried solving number two. Is  $\exists x \in R \; \exists k\in Z \; (x\; =\; k^2)$ correct ?

Comment: Yes: this is correct. For the first one, $\forall n,m \in \Bbb{N} \ \exists a,b,c \in \Bbb{N} \  an=c=bm$.

Comment: You solved Nr.$2$ correctly. Nr.$1$ is in words : For all natural numbers $a$ and $b$, there are natural numbers $u,v$ with  $ua=vb$